# How to return number of occurred element in list?

Tags: python

I'm sorry for the inrelevent topic title, because I couldn't find the proper name for the problem that I have:

I have the following Segment IDs:

```py
SIDs = ['11','22','33','44']
```

each element of `SID` has 2 items, like the following:

```py
 SID[0] = ['T10','T11']
 SID[1] = ['T20','T21']
 SID[2] = ['T30','T31']
 SID[3] = ['T40','T41']
```

Let's say I have the following Segment IDs which is defined as the following:

```py
SegmentPath = ['11','22','33','11','22','33']
```

In term of elements, the `SegmentPath` I want to build an output items as the following:

```py
Used_Path = ['T10', 'T20', 'T31', 'T21', 'T10', 'T20', 'T21']
```

**EDIT**

If you notice, each element of `SIDs` which is occurred in `SegmentPath` is repeated once as long as it is going in order (`11, 22` and `33`). But when it reaches 33, it used `T31` and the way back to `11` is which `T21`. Once we reach `11`, we use the same thing to reach `22` and `33`.

It is summarised in the figure below:

[image]

Then I return the iteration of each item occurred in `Used_Path` which should be the following:

```py
Used_Path_items = ['T10', 'T20', 'T21','T31']
iteration = [2, 2, 1, 1]
```

Is there anyway to do such thing in python? I appreciate if somebody gives some hints or code in python to help.

Comment: Are you looking for the count of each each item in `Used_Path` based on the order in which it appears in `Used_Path_Items`? (which would be `[2, 2, 2, 1]`)

Comment: @Deepstop Exactly, first I want to build `Used_Path` according to the `SegmentPath` then  return  `[2, 2, 1, 1]`

Comment: I will need to change my answer, but I don't understand how you get from Used_Path to SegmentPath? One has 6 items and the other has 7.

Comment: @TimLuka I'd suggest going through some tutorials on how to use common data structures in Python.  your `SIDs` and `SID` arrays look like they should be a single `dict`

Comment: @Deepstop I have edited my question. I hope it helps to understand both Used_Path to SegmentPath

Comment: Thanks. I'm still not clear on one thing. How, from the data you supplied, can you determine that `11` connects to `22` via `T10` and `T21` and not through, say, `T11` and `T20` or some other combination?

Comment: @Deepstop If you look at the `Segment_path` there is `33` after `22` which means we take the ones that end with zeros as they are doing transmission. In other words, (`T10`, `T20`, `T30`) are being used for transmission. Unless, when it returns back, the others items must be used as transmission as well (Like `T31` and `T21`)

Comment: I see now. So that yields 2 more questions. 1. How do you determine to go from `33` to `11` through `22` and not `44`? (2) The last Segment is `33`, but the last path `T21` goes from `22` to `11`. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is now more complicated. Hopefully this captures things. I've made some assumptions. (1) We don't wrap around from `44` to `11` (2) That `Used_Path` in your question has 1 too many elements.

So we follow a linear path, going forward if the destination is later, backwards otherwise. Then we just count the traversals in the same way as my original answer.

```
SIDs = ['11', '22', '33', '44']

SID = [['T10','T11'], 
       ['T20','T21'],
       ['T30','T31'],
       ['T40','T41']
]

SegmentPath = ['11','22','33','11','22','33']

Used_Path = []

for i in range(len(SegmentPath) - 1):
    depart = SIDs.index(SegmentPath[i])
    arrive = SIDs.index(SegmentPath[i+1])
    if arrive > depart:
        for j in range(depart, arrive, 1):
            Used_Path.append(SID[j][0])
    elif arrive < depart:
        for j in range(depart, arrive, -1):
            Used_Path.append(SID[j][1])
print(Used_Path)
print([Used_Path.count(t) for t in sorted(set(Used_Path))])
```

You could shorten from `if arrive > depart` with the following. A little less clear so I will leave the original as well.

```
for i in range(len(SegmentPath) - 1):
    depart = SIDs.index(SegmentPath[i])
    arrive = SIDs.index(SegmentPath[i+1])
    dir = 1 if arrive > depart else -1
    for j in range(depart, arrive, dir):
        Used_Path.append(SID[j][-1*dir]
print(Used_Path)
print([Used_Path.count(t) for t in sorted(set(Used_Path))])
```

This version will not work well if the same segment appears twice in a row.

Comment: thanks, first I want to build `Used_Path` according to the `SegmentPath` then  return  `[2, 2, 1, 1]`

Comment: Updated to do that, based on some assumptions about the task.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `collections.Counter`, something like:

```
from collections import Counter

Used_Path = ['T10', 'T20', 'T31', 'T21', 'T10', 'T20', 'T21'] 

c = Counter(Used_Path)

Used_Path_items = list(c.keys())
iteration = list(c.values())
```

but leaving these in the `Counter` object and using `.items()` is probably more useful

Comment: Thanks @Sam Mason! But Also I want to build first  `Used_Path ` according to the `SegmentPath` then  return `[2, 2, 1, 1]`